# Binding data frame with uneven entries by position

Tags: r, database

I have a number of data frames with different number of entries.
That look like that.

```
 chrom    pos   
2   chr1    88170   0.75
3   chr1    88203   1
4   chr1    88360   1
5   chr1    88387   1
6   chr1    88455   0.5
7   chr1    88486   1
8   chr1    88490   1
9   chr1    88510   1
10  chr1    88517   1
```

How can I bind them by the position variable and if a position  doesn't much I would like it to be with NA value.

Comment: Try with `merge` or one of the `join` methods. Place the datasets in a `list` and then do the join `library(tidyverse); lst(dat1, dat2, dat3, ...) %>% reduce(full_join, by = "pos")`

Comment: You should also show what you tried with an [edit]